# How To Use jest.spyOn on a function inside of functional component

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component I wanna test and I cant use spyOn on any of its internal methods as I can't reach them.

I was going along this tutorial [TDD With React, Jest, and Enzyme](https://testdriven.io/blog/tdd-with-react-jest-and-enzyme-part-two/#click-event-tests)

but I wanted to make the Calculator functional as i wanna learn more how it works in order to use hooks in the future.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Calculator.css';
import Display from "../Display/Display";
import Keypad from "../Keypad/Keypad";

const Calculator = () => {
  // value to be displayed in <Display />
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState('0');

  // values to be displayed in number <Keys />
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '.', '0','ce']);

  // values to be displayed in operator <Keys />
  const [operators, setOperators] = useState(['/', 'x', '-', '+']);

  // operator selected for math operation
  const [selectedOperator, setSelectedOperator] = useState('');

  // stored value to use for math operation
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState('');

  const callOperator = () => {
    console.log('call operation');
  };

  const setOperator = () => {
    console.log('set operation');
  };

  const updateDisplay = () => {
    console.log('update display');
  };

  return(
    <div className="calculator-container" >
      <Display displayValue={displayValue} />
      <Keypad
        callOperator={callOperator}
        numbers={numbers}
        operators={operators}
        setOperator={setOperator}
        updateDisplay={updateDisplay}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calculator;
```

here's the test
I can't reach the updateDisplay directly so I get the Keypad props (as I am passing it to that component) and mock it from there but it seems to be the wrong way, anyone has a way to do it better or suggest a better way to mock that function.

```
describe('mounted <Calculator />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let keypad;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Calculator/>);
    keypad = wrapper.find(Keypad);
  });

  it('calls updateDisplay when a number key is clicked', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.find(Keypad).props(), 'updateDisplay');
    wrapper.update();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    wrapper.find('.number-key').first().simulate('click');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.